# gdb error while trying to call getsockopt

Tags: sockets, tcp, gdb

I am trying to get TCP socket options for an existing TCP connection made through telnet to a remote server.

I tried to use gdb and call the getsockopt function but got an error:

Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure.

Is there a way to fix this? Are there any other ways to get TCP socket options for an existing TCP connection. I can get getsockopt to run within Python on a TCP socket that I create in my Python code. But I want to get details on an existing TCP connection created outside of python socket programming?

I got my fd and pid:

**#ss -tanope dst xx.xx.xx.xx**

State            Recv-Q            Send-Q                        Local Address:Port                          Peer Address:Port            Process
ESTAB            0                 0                             172.31.37.109:50970                         xx.xx.xx.xx:80               users:(("telnet",pid=6681,fd=3)) ino:74309 sk:17 cgroup:unreachable:1 <->

Then I did the following with gdb (I am new to gdb) but I got this error:

**#gdb**

GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.0.1-36.amzn2.0.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".

**(gdb) file /bin/telnet**

Reading symbols from /bin/telnet...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/telnet.debug...done.
done.

**(gdb) attach 6681**

Attaching to program: /usr/bin/telnet, process 6681

Reading symbols from /lib64/libutil.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libutil-2.26.so.debug...done.
done.

Reading symbols from /lib64/libncurses.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libncurses.so.6.0.debug...done.
done.

Reading symbols from /lib64/libtinfo.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.6.0.debug...done.
done.

Reading symbols from /lib64/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so.debug...done.
done.

Reading symbols from /lib64/libdl.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libdl-2.26.so.debug...done.
done.

Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/ld-2.26.so.debug...done.
done.

0x00007f1309a00397 in __GI___select (nfds=nfds@entry=4, readfds=0x55923c2b3800, writefds=0x55923c2b3820, exceptfds=exceptfds@entry=0x55923c2b3840,
timeout=timeout@entry=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/select.c:41
41        return SYSCALL_CANCEL (select, nfds, readfds, writefds, exceptfds,

(gdb) **call getsockopt(3, socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_QUICKACK)**

**Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure.**

(gdb)

Comment: Please learn how to format code in your questions so it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

> `call getsockopt(3, socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_QUICKACK)`

What do you expect GDB to do with `socket.IPPROTO_TCP` ?

As far as GDB is concerned, `socket` is the address of the `socket` function inside `libc.so`, and the expression `socket.IPPROTO_TCP` makes no sense as a `C` expression (which is exactly what GDB tells you).

What you likely want is:

```
(gdb) set $val = (int*)malloc(4)
(gdb) print getsockopt(/*fd*/3, /*IPPROTO_TCP*/6, /*TCP_QUICKACK*/12, $val, /*sizeof(int)*/4)

# Assuming above call printed 0 (i.e. succeeded)
(gdb) print *$val
```

Alternatively, and assuming your GDB was built with Python support, something like this might work:

```
(gdb) python import socket
(gdb) python print(socket.getsockopt(3, socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_QUICKACK))
```